# img alt changing image dimensions

Tags: css, html, alt

For some reason, when I added an alt tag to some images on my site, it changed their dimensions.

Alt tags

```
<table id="sidebar">
  <tr id="sidebar">
   <td><img src="images/photos/venetian_sample.gif" alt="venetian blind icon"></td>
   <td id="sidebar"><a href="blinds.html#venetian">Venetian Blinds</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

No alt tags

```
<table id="sidebar">
  <tr id="sidebar">
   <td><img src="images/photos/venetian_sample.gif"></td>
   <td id="sidebar"><a href="blinds.html#venetian">Venetian Blinds</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

They are both using the same stylesheet, and otherwise have the exact same HTML in that div.

Anyone know why this would be? I am aware the images aren't loading. They haven't been made yet. But I would like to solve this in the event they don't load in the future so it doesn't end up making my body disappear.

Comment: All the images are 404'ing?

Comment: If you mean the size of the images as they are now, it probably has something to do with the length of the alt text. You can set the size using CSS to make sure they are all uniform.

Comment: Yeah I haven't created the images yet, but they will be 50*50px.

Comment: A question should contain code needed to reproduce the problem. Links to live pages are not enough. Oh, and there is no “alt tag”.

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble formatting code on this site. Inserting it never seems to work, and there is a lot to demonstrate this issue. I modified the question title

Comment: By the way @dweeman, your server keeps timing out, you may want to look into that.

Comment: @Dweeman, please read my updated answer and the comments I posted below it. (I believe I rectified the problem you were having.)

Comment: Hmm, that's not good. I use nearly free speech, they are usually considered very reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this "issue" is because your images don't exist yet and therefor they aren't being found. `alt` tags are meant to display text when an image can not be located and that is exactly what is happening. When you do get around to uploading your images they will be the exact size they are supposed to be (as specified in the CSS or HTML). In short, alt tags don't affect your image's dimensions unless the browser can't display/find said images.

Please see the link below. I edited your HTML to include a picture that the browser could find. As you can see the dog image is not affected my the very long `alt` tag (which is a full paragraph).

http://jsfiddle.net/RWLFG/4/

Also, here is another example that very clearly demonstrates what I was explaining above:

http://jsfiddle.net/P4X58/2/

(Please note that the `alt` text will not display in Chrome due to a rendering bug.)

**Update:**
Ok, it appears you are referring to the fact that the text you entered in between your `<p>` tags isn't visible. To fix this remove `float:left` from the `#container` in your CSS. Please see the example below. (By the way, the paragraph text is hidden in both of the links you provided, not really sure why you thought the `alt` tags had anything to do with the issue, but I digress). Also, there are quite a few bugs in your code, I would highly recommend validating it with the official [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

http://jsfiddle.net/RWLFG/7/

Comment: I understand this. I haven't created the images yet. But I inserted the alts to see how they would display for the timebeing. So if the images can be found it works. But if they can't, the body disappears. I'd like to fix this issue rather than just have functional images with the issue possibly happening in the future.

Comment: @dweeman if you specify the dimensions in the HTML or CSS, even if the image can't be found the binding box will remain the correct size. Please see this [exampe:](http://jsfiddle.net/P4X58/3/). Could you clarify what you mean by having "the body disappear"? I'm not exactly sure what you're wanting to do...

Comment: @Dweeman, here's an example of specifying the images' dimensions on your website [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/RWLFG/5/).

Comment: Hey elle, thanks for getting back to me. This is sorted out now. If you check out my website linked above, you can see this in action.

What I mean by having the body disappear is, when it gets to a minimum width, instead of resizing, it starts to go out to the side, making the website side-scrollable. If you look at my website, it starts to happen to my sidebar at certain widths. I'm trying to stop resizing at a certain point, and then the padding on the right of the container to start going out of view to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers will specifically display the `alt` text when an image isn't found, that's obviously the point of the attribute.

You can specify a width/height inline or through css and it should clip the text at those dimensions. That's good practice anyway for images, so the browser still knows what dimension it should use

Comment: I've done alt {width: 10px; height: 10px;} in css, but it doesn't seem to work. Is that incorrect?

Comment: This is a good answer, but I felt the need to expand and clarify things a bit. In any case, +1 @helion3!